# php displaying "; ?> no matter what I do

Tags: php

I have been trying to follow the code written on youtube for creating a comment section for my website.

I use the following code for the form:

```
<?php

echo "<form>
<input type=-'hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
<input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
<textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>Comment</button>
<form>";
?>
```

However, when I preview in browser it shows the Comment button followed by ""; ?>"

[image: Image of what it shows in the preview -]
Everything is within the proper fields - I cannot figure out for the life of me what I am doing wrong - I followed the video to the T, and there are tons of comments saying that the code works - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LmPeHX7RRo

Any ideas?

Comment: I just realized that the ending form is not </form> I fixed it, but still having the same issue

Comment: Remove the closing tag, it will simple cause you no end of drama as you'll see from @LukasBach 's link

Comment: You need to run PHP through a server so it’s interpreted; you’re viewing it as HTML.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to avoid the closing `?>` in PHP only files, however this should not cause a problem. There might be a problem with your server configuration. Can you find something useful in your logs?

Comment: You're opening the file locally in your browser, i.e. without a web server running PHP, so the PHP isn't being parsed and interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

As the @Ed Cottrell's comment says, you can't just run PHP without a server, try installing [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/)

Also, there are 2 problems with the HTML: `type=-"hidden"` in the first input should be `type="hidden"`, and the closing form that you fixed already.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've never asked for help before - I really appreciate it!

Comment: you're welcome, go ahead, install wampserver and you will be ready to go :-)